# WPF, MVVM, Business Object with Validation don't match very good

Tags: wpf, mvvm, business-rules, idataerrorinfo

For my WPF-Application I decided for MVVM. Here is my Concept how I will implement this pattern.

- My Models (Business Objects) are responsible for the validation (that's a must for me).
- ViewModels are responsible to wrap my Model for a friendly User-Interaction and some security aspects.

My first question was about wrap or not wrap my Model in ViewModel.

- When I don't wrap my Model in ViewModel and expose the Model directly to the view – then I don't understand why I need a ViewModel (it seems sensless)
- `ViewModel` should wrap the Model for various reasons:

  1. I don't like direct binding to the strongly typed properties in Model (DateTime, int, …), because when I do this => WPF takes control over my validation for this types. That's really bad, because when the user write ‘aaaa’ in a Datepicker, my Model is valid (my model never know about that, because WPF takes the control over strongly typed properties) and the Save-Button is enable – that's really wrong.
  2. I don't expose all properties of my Model to the view, my `ViewModel` should protect my Model (I have some properties, that should have at presentation layer only getter and no setter)

My Decision is that `ViewModel` should definitely wrap the Model. So the `ViewModel` implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

But now I have problem with the business validation.

When I take the nice IDataErrorInfo, then I have the whole business rules in the ViewModel, that's breaks my concept. The business rules should definitely be in the model.

Example: When user choose Type A, then Field 1, and Field 2 are mandatory. When user choose Type B, then Field 3 is mandatory – this field should be marked as red and the Save-Button is disable when is it not valid. Also more heavy things like free/occupied DateTime-Ranges.

It's definitely bad, when I do this things in ViewModel, because most things are business part.

So how I can achieve this?

At the Moment I have this workaround:

All `ValidationRules` are in the Model as simple Methods, e.g.

```
public string ValidateBirthday(string birthay)
{
    if (...)
    {
        return "Birthday should be…";
    }
    return string.Empty;
}
```

In my ViewModel I implemented the IDataErrorInfo, and redirect to my Model-Validation like this:

```
public string this[string columnName]
{
    get
    {
        switch (columnName)
        {
            case "Birthday":
                return Model.ValidateBirthday(Birthday);
            case "XXX":
                return Model.ValidateXXX(XXX);
            case "YYY":
                return Model.ValidateYYY(YYY);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

I never see something like this (the redirect to Model) in an example, so I'm very doubtful about my implementation.

Is my workaround OK or do you see any problems about this?

I try to give more information about what I mean…

I know about the implementation INotifyPropertyChanged and IDataErrorInfo in the Model.

This works good with direct Binding from View to Model.

1. Direct Binding from View to Model:

   public class PersonViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
   {
       private Person _personModel;
       public Person PersonModel
       {
           get { return _personModel; }
           set
           {
               if (_personModel != value)
               {
                   _personModel = value;
                   NotifyPropertyChanged();
               }
           }
       }

   ```
   public PersonViewModel(Person person)
   {
       PersonModel = person;
   }
   …
   ```

   }

View:

```
<DatePicker Text="{Binding PersonModel.Birthday}"/>
```

The big disadvantage is: WPF takes the Control over all strong typed Property.

Example:
The user typed 07/20/2008 in the datepicker, so the PersonModel will be informed and PersonModel can check this, when OK, then PersonModel is valid => SaveButton is enable.

Now the user typed 'aaa' in the datepicker, WPF takes the control over this validation, because it's a binding to a strongly typed property (DateTime). PersonModel will not be informed about that, so the PersonModel is still valid => SaveButton is enable!

So for that 'problem' I need the `ViewModel` correctly.

2. ViewModel wrap the Model like this:

   public class PersonViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
   {
       private Person _personModel;

   ```
   public string Birthday
   {
       get
       {
           if (_personModel. Birthday!= null)
           {
               return ((DateTime) _personModel. Birthday).ToShortDateString();
           }
           else
           {
               return String.Empty;
           }
       }
       set
       {
           if (_personModel. Birthday.ToString() != value)
           {
               DateTime dateValue;
               if (DateTime.TryParse(value, out dateValue))
               {
                   _personModel.Birthday = dateValue;
                   …
               }
               else
               {
                   …
               }
           }
       }    
   }

   public PersonViewModel(Person person)
   {
       _personModel = person;
   }
   …
   ```

   }

Now I don't bind the Model direct from View. I bind the Properties from ViewModel that wrapped the Model.

```
<DatePicker Text="{Binding Birthday}"/>
```

The big advantage is: now I have the full control about what the user types in the fields.
When the user types strings like 'aaa' in Datepicker I can catch this => set the state to invalid and SaveButton is disabled.

That's one reason, why I don't take the direct binding from View to Model.
Other reason are readonly Property. In Model I have get and set on every Property, but for security Issue I won't offer all Properties from Model with get and set. So this can also solved by ViewModel by wrapping this Properties with only get. With direct Binding you can't do all this things.

My point is, I will definitely wrap all Properties from my Model in ViewModel, but how can I use the nice `IDataErrorInfo` in Model (It works only with direct Binding)?

Comment: Try implementing the `IDataErrorInfo` interface in your *model*, or *data type* classes, not your view model. When written correctly, WPF, MVVM and the `IDataErrorInfo` interface *actually* go together beautifully. Also, a view model does not just wrap a model class... instead, it should provide *all of the required data and functionality* to its related view. Please go and read up about these technologies/methodologies before you come here to complain about them without understanding. This is *not* a website that you can come to in order to learn these things.

Comment: Thank you for your response. But I don't expose by model directly to my view. This is because of the strongly typed properties in Model (DateTime, int, …). Example: Birthday is a DateTime. So when i directly bind to the view, wpf takes control over this property. When a user override the date with 'aaa' in datepicker, my model is never inform about that and my model is in valid state - that's wrong. When i wrap my model in viewmodel, then birthday is DateTime in Model and string in ViewModel - so i have now the control over this property and not wpf.

Comment: And how would wrapping your model in a view model help you in this particular situation? How would that stop your model from becoming out of sync with the UI?

Comment: I extended my Question with more Information about this.

Comment: Wow! So, you want to wrap all properties in `string`s, eh? You'll lose all the built in .NET type functionality, such as `string.Format`, etc., so good luck with that idea! That is *so* not the way to go. The `IDataErrorInfo` interface is for *data* errors, not UI errors... the clue is in the name. If a user enters 'AAA' into a `DatePicker`, why would you want to know that invalid value in the model? The '*big disadvantage*' that you speak about isn't really a disadvantage at all... at least, neither I nor my many users of my WPF applications have ever found it to be a problem.

Comment: We validate *data* errors from the model using the `IDataErrorInfo` interface and we validate UI errors (such as a user attempting to enter a letter into a numerical field) in the UI by handling events.

Comment: So i will implement IDataErrorInfo and INotifyPropertyChanged in the Model. Then direct bind view to model via viewmodel (like 1. Direct Binding from View to Model). And an event for textchange in Datapicker when user type 'aaa' - so i can handle this things in viewmodel and disable the SaveButton. How do you handle DateTime with no DefaultValue? Example new Person - the value in datepicker should be empty - via converter?

Comment: I would set the default `DateTime` value to be either `DateTime.MinValue` or `DateTime.MaxValue` and then use a `Converter` to detect either of these values and to output a `Not set` message in the actual control.

Comment: Typically the model implements IDataErrorInfo and the *viewmodel* implements INotifyPropertyChanged in this style of architecture. Typically.

Comment: It's MVVM, not VVM.  Models carry data, but can also perform validation--it's their data, anyhow. ViewModels intermediate between the user (with the help of the UI) and the business logic of the application, presenting models with logic processed data for display, and transmitting alterations to these models back to the logic.  It isn't that hard.

Answer (score 3):

You are mixing two concepts here: Bussiness objects and validation.

Almost every system nowadays uses the client-server architecture, even if its an standalone application.

In such scenario you have two validation locations:

- The **client** is responsible for ensuring that the data entered is valid before sending anything to the server in order to enhance user experience and avoid server overloads and security issues.
- The **server** is responsible for the verification of the incoming data, to avoid malformed, misformatted data and security issues.

Also:

- The **Bussiness Objects** (BO) are the classes used by server, tipically represeting the data base.
- The **Data Transfer Objects** (DTO) are the classes that the server sends to the client.
- The **ViewModels** are both the backend code for the UI and the wrappers for the DTOs.

Your model objects shouldn't have any logic, since you will spoil them with some code that at some point you will need to reuse.

As exposed here, you should separate that validation logic into services that only know about that object and how to validate them. This way, you can use validation services from the UI.

Your `Save` button should react only on UI changes, and you will only get those from a ViewModel.

Basically, you will be applying [SOLID principles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29) here: Each layer has very clear responsibilities (model -> data, services -> validation, dto -> data ready for the client, viewmodels -> UI interaction). All the code will be easy to work with, easy to extend and easy to refactor.

### Edit

**1st and 2nd questions**:
UI only validates the input: no random characters in number fields, no sql characters in text fields, Date has correct format, etc.

Thinks like "if this then that" should be handled by the backend, as you describe:

1. Save is clicked.
2. UI data is valid.
3. DTO sent to backend.
4. Backend analizes DTO and it is not valid.
5. Backend sends back the errors found.
6. UI shows the errors found.

**3rd question**:
That looks right to me.

**4th question**:
DTO is just a concept, you can use a real backend server that communicates via WCF, or you can just have a bunch of classes that act as a service but are called in the same application domain (like any other project reference). In either case you can choose what data is being sent and received.

You should start developing in that direction and then see what better fits you.

Comment: Thanks for you detailed answer. That sounds right to me.

The BO and DTO don’t knows about their own valid State?
It’s always another Object that knows this (ViewModel in PL with simple Rules, Service in BL with more heavy rules).

Example 1: 
When user choose Type A, then Field 1 and Field 2 are mandatory. 
When user choose Type B, then Field 3 is mandatory.
This are simple stupid Validation Rules and I can do it in ViewModel?

Comment: Example 2: 
DateFrom – DateTo must be in a Date-Range that’s free (like a Reservation in a Restaurant).
This is not a Validation Rule but Business Rule (?), so the User try Save – the Request goes to Business and Business will send a Message back, when the Range is not free – right?
Is it overhead, when the Service check’s the Validations Rules from Example 1 again (for more stability) before Save?

Comment: What about ListViewModel and EditViewModel?
I have a List with Persons (read-only). The user can add/update/delete Persons (with a new Form, not in the Grid itself).
When the user will save the changes, the Request goes first to the BO-Service and then the BO-Service will send a Message. The ListPersonVM , who is listen to that Message, will refresh this Person in the List (or add/delete) – right? No communication between the EditPersonVM and ListPersonVM – always via BO-Layer (it could be, that the business makes some calculation or whatever – so that makes sense).

Comment: My wpf Application is a fat client, so the PL and the BL are on the same machine, so I can do the whole things without DTO (?).

Sorry about my many questions, I do this layering for the first time.